# the meaning "off"

Tags: prepositions

> Emergency services were found on Aberdeen's Marywell street, off College Street, on Friday.

What is meaning of the *off*? Is it preposition or adverb?

Comment: [off](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/off?q=off#off__16).

Answer (score 2):

It means that Marywell Street is a side street from College Street in Aberdeen.